# Action Script 3, Flash Develop. Error I don't know how to resolve

Tags: actionscript-3

---

The error I am getting is:

```
F:\Game Techniques\FireBoy&WaterGirl\src\Hero.as(11): col: 3: Error:
An Embed variable must not have an existing value.

[Embed(source="../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]
```

Please can you explain what this means and how I resolve it.

Here is the full code

```
package  
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Harry
     */
    public class Hero extends Sprite
    {
        [Embed(source="../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]

        public var grav:int = 0;
        public var floor:int = 580;

        private static const HeroFireBoy:Class;
        private var FireBoy:Bitmap;

        public function Hero() 
        {
            FireBoy = new Hero.HeroFireBoy();
            scaleX = 0.1;
            scaleY = 0.1;

            addChild(FireBoy);
        }
        public function adjust():void 
        {
            FireBoy.y += grav;
            if(FireBoy.y+FireBoy.height/2<floor)
                grav++;
            else 
            {
                grav = 0;
                FireBoy.y = floor - FireBoy.height / 2;
            }
            if (FireBoy.x - FireBoy.width / 2 < 0)
                FireBoy.x = FireBoy.width / 2;
            if (FireBoy.x + FireBoy.width / 2 > 800)
                FireBoy.x = 800 - FireBoy.width / 2;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give some more info on @Kir's answer; when you embed something, you need to associate it with with a variable of type `Class`, so that you can create it later. This is done via:

```
[Embed(source = "../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]
private var fireBoyClass:Class;
```

Because, in your example, the line with `fireBoyClass` doesn't exist, Flash thinks that you're trying to associate it with the line

```
public var grav:int = 0;
```

Which is what's giving you the error.

Once you have your `Class` property declared, you can then create an instance of your embedded data:

```
public var fireBoyBitmap:Bitmap = ( new fireBoyClass ) as Bitmap;
```

This post (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60546-7ff2.html) gives a good overview of the `[Embed]` metatag - just concentrate on the code between the `<fx:Script>` and ignore the `[Bindable]` metatag - that's only useful for flex.

Answer (score 2):

It can happen if you after line:

`[Embed(source="../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]`

declare some variable with value. 
For example:

`[Embed(source="../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]
private var fireBoyClass:Class = null;`

Generally, after `[Embed(source="../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]` next line should be declaration of variable that associated with embedded source.

```
public class SomeClass 
{
    [Embed(source = "../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]
    private var fireBoyClass:Class;
```

In your case just move line `private static const HeroFireBoy:Class;` under
`[Embed(source = "../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]`

Finaly it will looks like:

```
public class Hero extends Sprite
{
    [Embed(source = "../assets/FireBoy.jpg")]
    private static const HeroFireBoy:Class;

    public var grav:int = 0;
    public var floor:int = 580;
```

Comment: public var grav:int = 0;
  public var floor:int = 580;
  private static const HeroFireBoy:Class;
  private var FireBoy:Bitmap;
  public function Hero() 
  {
   FireBoy = new Hero.HeroFireBoy();
   scaleX = 0.1;
   scaleY = 0.1;
   addChild(FireBoy);
  }
  public function adjust():void 
  {
   FireBoy.y += grav;
   if(FireBoy.y+FireBoy.height/2<floor)
    grav++;
   else 
   {
   grav = 0;
    FireBoy.y = floor - FireBoy.height / 2;
   }
   if (FireBoy.x - FireBoy.width / 2 < 0)
    FireBoy.x = FireBoy.width / 2;
   if (FireBoy.x + FireBoy.width / 2 > 800) FireBoy.x = 800 - FireBoy.width / 2;}

Comment: Please show me the code before and after [Embed...]

Comment: NOTE: it should just be `private var fireBoyClass:Class;`, not `private var fireBoyClass:Class = null;`, as with the latter, you'll get the same error